# Authlogic and Invalid Sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

**Background**:

I've inherited an older Rails application which I'm attempting to setup a local copy and have run into a problem with the Authlogic gem used for authentication.  The setup is as follows:

- Rails 2.3.18 application which is a legacy application
- Using Authlogic for authentication.
- Unable to create a valid session

**Testing**:

The application has a User model and it's constructed using the simple steps outlined in [AuthLogic Quick Rails example](http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic#Quick_Rails_example).  The login step routes to the UserSessions controller to take the user parameters (login and password), creates a new session then attempts to save the session, like so:

```
UserSessionsController.rb

....

@user_session = current_account.user_sessions.new(params[:user_session])

if @user_session.save
   # login success
   ....
else
  # login failure
end
```

It's the last step that's failing. And when I check the errors on the @user_session object I'm getting the string "**Login is not valid**"

Additionally I've tested this via the rails console and followed the instructions as per the article:  [Working with Authlogic in console](http://www.tatvartha.com/2009/09/working-with-authlogic-in-scriptconsole/).  This basically requires that in the console you execute:

```
Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(self)
```

Using this method when I simulate the UserSession creation via a call like:

```
us=UserSession.new(:login=> "user@gmail.com", :password => "secret")
```

I get the error:  `#<UserSession: no credentials provided>`

Now in both cases the user identity exists in the DB.

Any tips/suggestions for fault diagnosis would be most welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to access the `current_account` convenience method in your `create` action, but you're presumably not logged in yet, so I'm not sure where `current_account` would be coming from. Does the following snippet work in place of your existing `@user_session` assignment?

```
# app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb
@user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - will give it a try and comment further.

Comment: No luck - still fails with error ["Login is not valid"].  Suspecting another problem with the UserSession possibly.

Comment: Have you verified that you're using correct credentials? Perhaps try creating a brand new user, e.g., `UserSession.create(:login => "bjohnson", :password => "my password", :remember_me => true)`. Then try signing in to that account?

Comment: Thanks - that worked.  I created a new user and was able to verify that it was working.  Thanks for the suggestion.